# Are DOD Young Investigator Research Program (YIP) grants transferable to new universities?

Tags: funding, tenure-track

Backstory: a colleague has a YIP with the AF, funded, and has been hired by a new university. The Program Officer is on personal leave (3 months now, no end in sight). He is pushing harder, and hearing non-options like 'don't go to the new post' and 'reapply'. Has anyone seen a DOD YIP move successfully?  If so, how?

Comment: Is there another program office he could contact?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your colleague's question is specific to his funding award, his program officer, and his specific situation. Only his program office or someone else from DoD could answer his this question. That being said, a [quick Google search](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=dod+young+investigator+award+transfer) found another funding request that describes general [DOD grant policies](http://cdmrp.army.mil/funding/pa/FY17-ARP-GAI.pdf):

> **Transfer of Award to New Organization:** Unless restricted by the specific Program
>   Announcement, a change in organizational affiliation will be considered on a case-by-case basis
>   by the USAMRAA Grants Officer. If approved, the PI’s original organization will be required to
>   agree to relinquish the award. The new organization will be required to resubmit the entire
>   application on behalf of the PI, including regulatory documentation. Extended times for transfer
>   may put the award funding at risk. A transfer will not, unless under extraordinary circumstances,
>   be allowed for any organization that includes a study site/clinical trial at its location.